# How to extend email-inline css in custom module

Tags: magento2, email-templates

I have extend email css in my custom module but its not working here is how i have extend it

```
Vender
Module
    web
        css
            source
                _email.less
```

but it's not working.

Comment: check this link - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/179203/magento-2-override-extend-the-email-css-that-is-being-used-in-the-transactional

Comment: yes tried but was not working