# Transactional Email Template

Tags: magento2

how i can add custom css in magento2 transitional Email Template .

I want add some ccs in file is it possible to add css in file and use in Template ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check these links.
[Magento 2: Override/extend the email.css that is being used in the transactional email header](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/179203/magento-2-override-extend-the-email-css-that-is-being-used-in-the-transactional)
https://nwdthemes.com/2018/05/25/how-to-style-email-templates-in-magento-2/
https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/frontend-core/guide/templates/email/